# Sails.js localization Not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Localization in sails.js not working for me. I have done all this like sails.js documentation but not working for me. Please check my code.This is my `i18n.js`

```
module.exports.i18n = {
  locales: ['en','fr', 'ar'],
  defaultLocale: 'ar',
  updateFiles: false,
  localesDirectory: '/config/locales'
};
```

But always my home page getting locale `en` .I have check using `req.getLocale` .If I write `req.setLocale` on the top of the function then page load using changed language but after refresh the page page getting default locale `en`.

Comment: Print the HTTP headers in the request and see if an "accept-language" header is set, then note it's value.

Comment: can't understand how to set.can you please help me.

Comment: In your controller action put console.log(req.headers); This will print all the request headers in the console. Look for the "accept-language" header and see what is the value. Maybe this header is causing your app to always show the pages in English.

Comment: Yes. this is printing 'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'. Arabic language is not accepting.what to do now ?

Comment: The whole point around localization is for the server to detect the language accepted by the agent (browser). So that is the purpose of the  "accept-language" header. If it is missing, the default locale is used, in your case 'ar'. However the browser is requesting 'en', so that is the language your server renders. To test your 'ar' locale, use a REST client and set your "accept-language" header to the 'ar'. You can always force the locale, but then the whole point of automatic localization would be lost. The other approach is to save the locale preference in the session and set it every time.

Comment: If a set locales only 'ar' and defaultLocale is 'ar' then the page comes in ar language but when we set multiple locales 'ar','en' and defaultLocale ar then page always in english.

Comment: In your locales: ['en','fr', 'ar'] array try to put 'ar' in the first place.